# Calculating probability: Buffon-Laplace Needle Problem

Tags: probability, statistics, geometric-probability

**Question**: Find the probability $P(l,a,b)$ that a needle of length $l$ will land on at least one line, given a floor with a grid of equally spaced parallel lines distances $a$ and $b$ apart, with $l<a,b$. The position of the needle can be specified with points $(x,y)$ and its orientation with coordinate $\theta$. By symmetry, we can consider a single rectangle of the grid, so $0<x<a$ and $0<y<b$. In addition, since opposite orientations are equivalent, we can take $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

**My Answer**: By symmetry, we consider a single rectangle. The probability for the needle to lie on side $a$ is $\frac{l}{a}$. Since rectangles have two sides, $P_a = \frac{2l}{a}$. Similarly, the probability for the needle to lie on side $b$ is $\frac{l}{b}$. Since rectangles have two other sides, $P_b = \frac{2l}{b}$. The total probability for the rectangle is $P_T = P_a*P_b = \frac{4l^2}{ab}$. Since orientation must also be considered, the total number of orientation are $2\pi$. But opposite orientations are equivalent so total orientation = $\frac{2\pi}{2} = \pi$. The probability for $l$ to be in any one of the orientation $P_\theta = \frac{1}{\pi}$. So the total probability of orientation and rectangle is $P_R = (\frac{4l^2}{ab})(\frac{1}{\pi}) = \frac{4l^2}{ab\pi}$.

Why isn't this the correct answer for the "Buffon-Laplace Needle Problem?"
What is the correct answer and how do you get it?

Comment: "The probability for the needle to lie on side $a$ is $l/a$"
You lost me there. Why?